# Unable to install breakpoint in <myClass>$$$view59 due to missing line number attributes. Reason: Absent Line Number Information

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I have a Java project, a Jboss 7.1.0 GA server and Maven for building.

I have configured my server in Eclipse adding my .ear files from the administration console. When I start it on debug mode in Eclipse, I receive the error message:

> Unable to install breakpoint in myClass$$$view59 due to missing line
>   number attributes. Reason: Absent Line Number Information.

I put my breakpoint in a bean class.
I saw the Java -> Compiler settings and the checkbox about the line number attributes was checked.

I know it is a duplicate, but I tried to solve my problem with the posts written in this site, but no one was useful.

Please help me

Edit: I tried to ignore it, but the debug is offset compared to the line number.

Comment: As a workaround, you should still be able to set method entry breakpoints.

Comment: @Thilo I solved my problem ignoring the error, my code was not updated... thank you !